# Sum with $2$ variable $i$ and $j$

Tags: summation

> Calculation of $\displaystyle\mathop{\sum\sum}_{1\leq i< j\leq n}ij$

When I expand that sum, I get

$\displaystyle[1(2+3+4+\cdots+n)+2(3+4+\cdots+n) $

$+3(4+5+6+\cdots+n)+\cdots (n-1)n]$

In each bracket sum in arthematic progression and we have to find individual sum

Is there is any better way to find its sum, have a look please.

Comment: Note that $$\underbrace{\sum_{1\leq i,j \leq n} ij}_{=(\sum_{i=1}^{n}i)^2} = \underbrace{\sum_{1\leq i=j\leq n} ij}_{=\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2} + 2\left( \sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}ij \right). $$ So, a formula for the sum can be easily derived from that for $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2$.

Comment: Thanks Sangchul Lee got it. Can we say same about $\displaystyle \mathop{\sum\sum\sum}_{1\leq <i<j\leq n}ijk=\frac{1}{3}[\sum_{1\leq i,j,k\leq n}ijk-(\mathop{\sum}_{1\leq i=j=k\leq n}ijk)]$

Comment: Unfortunately, no. In general you will need a suitable combination of sums over the ranges $$ 1\leq i,j,k\leq n, \qquad 1\leq i=j<k\leq n, \qquad 1\leq i<j=k\leq n, \qquad 1\leq i=j=k\leq n. $$ So, the trick quickly goes out of hand for higher-order versions.

Comment: Thanks Sangchul Lee